# Cannot access Adafruit Feather 32u4

Tags: 16.04, modem-manager, arduino

I have properly installed

- a **new** version of arduino IDE (at least `1.6.0`)
- the `adafruit AVR boards` library

The device shows up under *Tools->Port* but I cannot upload data to the device.

I get the following error:

```
Erzwinge Reset durch öffnen/schließen mit 1200 bps auf dem Port /dev/ttyACM0
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
   at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:141)
   at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:78)
   at processing.app.Sketch.upload(Sketch.java:1186)
   at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1160)
   at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1132)
   at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2381)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Fehler beim Ansprechen des seriellen Ports "/dev/ttyACM0".
   at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:87)
   at   cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:130)
... 6 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/ttyACM0; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
   at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
   at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:81)
... 7 more
```

The device has a properly installed bootloader and I am able to access it from other operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

`ModemManager` keeps the device busy it is a reported and confirmed [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1473246) but it is not yet fixed.

You can check it using

```
sudo lsof | grep ACM
```

## Solution

**Quick fix**
If you just need to upload a program for one time and you have to make it fast
the easiest way to handle the problem is to just stop `ModemManager` for a second.

```
sudo systemctl stop ModemManager.service
```

Will halt `Modemmanager` and now you can access the device.
**Be sure** to start `ModemManager` after you uploaded stuff to your device:

```
 sudo systemctl start ModemManager.service
```

**Persistent Fix**
It is much better to apply `udev` rules to prevent this error. you can download finished `udev` rules from Adafruit and follow [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-ide-setup/linux-setup#udev-rules) to install them.

**Tip**
As Ubuntu does not provide the modern versions of arduino IDE you should install the IDE *locally* by [downloading](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) it and unzipping the archive.